# Function with bounded derivatives on punctured plane

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

This is a past exam question that ought to be easy, that I was unable to piece together.

The question is to suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ has the following properties:

$f(-\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}) = 0$, $|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)| \leq |\sin(x^2 + y^2)|$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus the origin, and $|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)| \leq |\cos(x^2 + y^2)|$ on the punctured plane as well.

The question is to show that $|f(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})| \leq 4$.

My idea was to observe that the distance between $(-\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2})$ and $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$ is 4, and to use the fact that the derivatives were bounded by functions which are in turn bounded by $1$. The problem was that I don't really know how to make this strategy materialize. For one variable this would be easy since $\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y}$ would be bounded by the mean value theorem, but here I need a little more.

Comment: seems like you have a typo: $(-\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)$?

Comment: Is $f$ differentiable on $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}?$

Comment: @zhw. I have corrected the typo. Yes $f$ is differentiable, but not necessarily $C^1$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what I'm seeing still doesn't say $f$ is (Frechet) differentiable.  Did your corrections get lost?

Comment: @fourierwho Perhaps there is more than one typo? I corrected a typo involving the point. The known point is $(-\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2})$. $f$ is differentiable, but these derivatives need not be continuous. I don't know what Frechet differentiability is.

Comment: Frechet differentiability in this case means $f((x,y) + (h,k)) = f(x,y) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) h + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) k + o(|h| + |k|)$.  When @zhw asked if $f$ was differentiable, I think he meant Frechet differentiable, which is stronger than just asking that the partial derivatives of $f$ exist.  At any rate, my response works if $f$ is Frechet differentiable, but I don't know what to do if it's not.

Comment: Incidentally, this question seems unreasonable if $f$ isn't Frechet differentiable.  Then again, it also seems unreasonable if $f$ isn't $C^{1}$ (since the difference in proof is just tedious technicalities) unless there's a much better proof than the one I gave.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $f$ is (Frechet) differentiable.  To make a long story short, we can still use the mean value theorem: if things are smooth, use the integral form; otherwise, use piecewise linear paths and the mean value theorem along line segments.  The details are fleshed out below.

**If we can assume $f$ is continuously differentiable,** then things are much better because we can use the following: if $c : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus \{0\}$ is piecewise $C^{1}$, then
$$f(c(1)) - f(c(0)) = \int_{0}^{1} \nabla f(c(t)) \cdot \dot{c}(t) \, dt.$$
By assumption and trig identities, $\|\nabla f(x)\| = 1$.  Thus,
$$\|f(c(1)) - f(c(0))\| \leq L(c),$$
where $L(c)$ denotes the length.  In our case, $c$ should be a piecewise $C^{1}$ path from $(-\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$ to $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$.  We can approximate the straight line path $c$ by consider a path $c^{\epsilon}$ that takes a small "detour" around zero whose length goes to zero as $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$.  (For concreteness, imagine we travel along $c$ to within a distance $\epsilon$ of zero, then follow the circle of radius $\epsilon$ counterclockwise until it intersects the path $c$ again, then follow $c$ to $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$.)  I leave it to you to prove that $L(c^{\epsilon}) \to L(c) = 4$ as $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$.  Thus, we get $|f(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})| \leq 4$.

**When $f$ is not continuously differentiable,** do the following: consider a piecewise linear path $c^{\epsilon} : [0,4] \to \mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus \{0\}$ that approximates the straight line $c : [0,4] \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ given by $c(t) = (1 - \frac{t}{4})(-\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2}) + \frac{t}{4}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$.  The simplest way to do this is to travel along $c$ until $t = 2 - \epsilon$, then go straight up by $\sqrt{2} \epsilon$, then straight to the right a distance $\sqrt{2} \epsilon$, then continue along $c$ as if nothing ever happened.  Along the vertical and horizontal pieces of $c^{\epsilon}$, we can apply the mean value theorem in the variables $x$ and $y$ individually and the change in $f$ will be at most $2 \epsilon$.  It remains to modify the mean value theorem so that we can find how much $f$ changes along $c \restriction_{[0,2 - \epsilon]}$ and $c \restriction_{[2 + \epsilon,4]}$.

This is reasonably straightforward.  Consider any straight line $b : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^{d}$ of the form $b(t) = (1 - t)v + t w$, where $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $d \in \mathbb{N}$.  If $f : U \to \mathbb{R}$ is (Frechet) differentiable (and $U$ is any subdomain of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ containing the image of $b$), then the function $g : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(t) = f(b(t))$ is differentiable and
$$g'(t) = \nabla f(b(t)) \cdot b'(t).$$
Applying the mean value theorem to $g$ at the endpoints, we get
$$|f(b(1)) - f(b(0)| = |g(1) - g(0)| = |\nabla f(b(c))\| \cdot b'(c)| \leq  \|\nabla f(b(c))\| \|v - w\|$$
for some $c \in [0,1]$.  Note the crucial step that $b'(t) = w - v$ identically.

Thus, returning to our $c^{\epsilon}$ and using the fact that $\|\nabla f(x,y)\| = 1$ everywhere, we see that
$$|f(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}) - f(-\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})| \leq \|c^{\epsilon}(2 - \epsilon) - (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})\| + \|c^{\epsilon}(2 - \epsilon) - c^{\epsilon}(2)\| + \|c^{\epsilon}(2) - c^{\epsilon}(2 - \epsilon)\| + \|c^{\epsilon}(2 - \epsilon) - (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})\| = L(c^{\epsilon}).$$
Taking $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$, we get $L(c^{\epsilon}) \to L(c) = 4$, yielding the result once again.

Comment: We don't know $f$ is differentiable, do we?